# Logout for External Provider

Tags: federated-authentication, sso

I am using Sitecore 10.2 and I have set up federated authentication for the end user, below are the steps:

- On the public website [www.website.com](http://www.website.com), there will be a login button
- When the user will click on the login button it will redirect to [www.something-sso.com](http://www.something-sso.com).
- User will enter username and password and after successful validation, it will redirect back to [www.website.com](http://www.website.com).
- On [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) website, logout button will visible
- On logout button it will redirect to [www.something-sso.com](http://www.something-sso.com) and it will logout and on [www.something-sso.com](http://www.something-sso.com) there will be a button "Return to home page".

Now problem is that when user click on "Return to home page" then it is redirecting to "www.website.com" and again coming on to "www.something-sso.com" but when I do logout and after 2 mins I click on "Return to home page" then it correctly redirect to "www.website.com".

Below is my logout code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
```

```
  public class ProjectIdentityProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
    {

        private readonly ICookieManager cookieManager;
        readonly string clientId = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ClientId");
        readonly string redirectUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RedirectUri");
        readonly string clientSecret = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ClientSecret");
        readonly string authority = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("Authority");
        readonly string postLogoutRedirectUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("PostLogoutRedirectUri");
        readonly string errorUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ErrorMessage");
        public ProjectIdentityProvider(
            FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
            ICookieManager cookieManager,
            BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
        {
            this.cookieManager = cookieManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cookieManager));
        }

        protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var saveSigninToken = identityProvider.TriggerExternalSignOut;

            var oidcOptions = this.SetupOidcOptions(authenticationType, saveSigninToken);

            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
        }

        public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SetupOidcOptions(
            string authenticationType,
            bool saveSigninToken)
        {
            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
              //  AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
               // ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                //RedeemCode = true,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                SaveTokens = true,
               //RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                },
                TokenValidationParameters =
            {
                SaveSigninToken = saveSigninToken
                  //ValidateIssuer = false
            },
               // CookieManager = cookieManager
            };

            return oidcOptions;
        }

        protected override string IdentityProviderName => "ProjectIdentityProvider";

        protected BaseLog Log { get; }

        public Collection<string> Scopes { get; } = new Collection<string>();

        private Task RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync(
            RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>
                notification)
        {
            //var domain = urlUtils.GetDomain();
            var owinContext = notification.OwinContext;
            var protocolMessage = notification.ProtocolMessage;
            var user = Sitecore.Context.User;
            if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
            {
                //var redirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;// this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(postLogoutRedirectUri);
                // Make sure the redirectUri goes to the current domain. 
               // redirectUri = WebUtil.GetUri(redirectUri, new Uri(domain)).ToString();
                protocolMessage.RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
            }

            if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
            {
               // var postLogoutRedirectUri = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(postLogoutRedirectUri);
                // Make sure the postLogoutRedirectUri goes to the current domain.
                //postLogoutRedirectUri = WebUtil.GetUri(postLogoutRedirectUri, new Uri(domain)).ToString();
                protocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
                protocolMessage.IdTokenHint = this.GetIdTokenHint(owinContext);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task SecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            foreach (var current in identityProvider.Transformations)
            {
                current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

```
    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
                <mapEntry name="sites with extranet domain" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:instead="*[@name='sites with extranet domain']">
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>Test</site>
                    </sites>
                    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='ProjectIdentityProvider']" />
                    </identityProviders>
                    <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <IsPersistentUser>false</IsPersistentUser>
                    </externalUserBuilder>
                </mapEntry>
            </identityProvidersPerSites>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="ProjectIdentityProvider" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                    <caption>Go to login</caption>
                    <domain>extranet</domain>
                    <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
                    <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
                    <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                        <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
                        <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                        <!-- If external authentication is configured with "TokenValidationParameters = {SaveSigninToken = true}", this saves the value from "claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext" to the "id_token" claim. -->
                        <transformation name="set id_token claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SaveIdTokenInClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                    </transformations>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
            <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <maps hint="list">
                    <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <data hint="raw:AddData">
                            <!--claim name-->
                            <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
                            <!--property name-->
                            <target name="Email" />
                        </data>
                    </map>
                    
                    
                    <map name="Given Name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <data hint="raw:AddData">
                            <!--<source name="given_name" />-->
                            <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
                            <target name="Name" />
                        </data>
                    </map>
                </maps>
            </propertyInitializer>
        </federatedAuthentication>
```

Comment: Please try this 
HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/", true);

And also check the details at 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32300/authenticationmanager-logout-does-not-trigger-external-owin-middleware-to-logout